# Blocking toast pop-ups without Xposed

Tags: android-10, toast-notifications

I'm currently running on a OnePlus 7Pro with OOS 10.3.2 (Android-10).

I've been using an Xposed module called "Untoaster Xposed" to selectively block toast popups based upon regex matches of the contained text. This works well, but now I am considering switching to Renovate Ice, which doesn't support Xposed or TaiChi, and I'm wondering if there is any non-Xposed-based method for selectively blocking toast popups in this or a similar manner.

I'm willing to write a custom app to do this, if it is the only alternative.

But is this even possible without Xposed?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think it would be best if you tell us whether you want to selectively block toasts from an app or do that in wholesale (that is, all toasts to be blocked from an app). If in wholesale, inbuilt appops can do this (for some apps).

Comment: Well, ideally, I'd like the same functionality as "Untoaster Xposed". It ignores the name of the app and just blocks by means of a regex match of the text within the toast. However, if that is not possible, blocking all toasts for a given app would be my second choice. I'll check out `appops`